# SOLR throws exception while trying to index spatial data

Tags: java, apache, solr

I've encountered a problem with SOLR 5.0 installation indexing of spatial fields

I've tried to index 
`<field name="geo">-74.093 41.042 -69.347 44.558</field>`
Like in the documentation at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4#Indexing

My geo is of type `location_rpt` and the definition of the field type is:

`<fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType" geo="false"/>`

The error that I've found in the logs is:

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Can't parse point '-74.093 41.042 -69.347 44.558' because: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "41.042 -69.347 44.558"

Somehow the first point is being dropped off

This however, works in previous installation of SOLR, namely 4.10, and I don't yet want to rely on `JTS` to index as `POLYGON`

Can anyone point me in the right direction of indexing a rectangular data in SOLR 5 without the need of `JTS` library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We were able to index rectangles in Solr 5.x (without using JTS Topology Suite) using the CQL ENVELOPE syntax. The CQL ENVELOPE syntax is briefly documented under the [BBoxField](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search?#SpatialSearch-BBoxField) is the Solr Wiki.

Example:

```
ENVELOPE(-10, 20, 15, 10) # ENVELOPE(minX, maxX, maxY, minY)
```

Note that this format uses a seemingly non-standard ordering.

For your example you should be able to index the following (assuming your original example was in "minX minY maxX maxY" format:

```
<field name="geo">ENVELOPE(-74.093, -69.347, 44.558, 41.042)</field>
```

The same syntax can be used when filtering or searching within documents.

```
"fq": "geo:\"Intersects(ENVELOPE(-74.093, -69.347, 44.558, 41.042))\""
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for me in Solr 7.6, when using `solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType` field.